# why does jQuery.load doesn't work for this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have some inner html that needs to be inserted into  a `div` which has the class `modal-body` like this:

```
$(".modal-body").load("http://cistrome.org/finder/util/pure_meta?did=1660");
```

Though [this page](http://cistrome.org/finder/util/pure_meta?did=1660) can be accessed by browser, it cannot be loaded into the `div`, when I checked the status of this ajax connection, it says "canceled".

I tried to set the timeout longer like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ timeout: 30000 });
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

It is because it might be violating [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

If the domain of your page and the page being loaded are different then the browser security system does not allow to make a ajax request to the resource and `load` uses ajax to load the content.

Answer (score 1):

Your requests should be from the [same domain](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

You could try to get the contents via PHP:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://cistrome.org/finder/util/pure_meta?did=1660");
```

EDIT: Not tested, but you might try this: https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/